# Pass list argument to zeep method

Tags: python, soap, zeep

I'm trying to call a soap method with zeep (v 3.4.0) and pass a list of objects to that method. Inspecting the xml presentation of the request shows an empty list.

```py
from lxml import etree
from requests import Session
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth  # or HTTPDigestAuth, or OAuth1, etc.
from zeep import Client
from zeep.transports import Transport

session = Session()
session.auth = HTTPDigestAuth('user', 'pass')
client = Client('http:service.local/services.wsdl',
    transport=Transport(session=session))

factory = client.type_factory('ns0')
o1 = factory.objectTypePrint('name1', 'val1')
o2 = factory.objectTypePrint('name2', 'val2')
o3 = factory.objectTypePrint('name3', 'val3')

node =  client.create_message(client.service, 'printFormat', numbers=1, jobID='test', objects=[o1,o2,o3])

print(etree.tostring(node, pretty_print=True))
```

The result looks like

```xml
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap-env:Body>
    <ns0:printFormatRequest xmlns:ns0="http://www.cab.de/WSSchema">
      <ns0:objects/>
      <ns0:jobID>test</ns0:jobID>
      <ns0:numbers>1</ns0:numbers>
    </ns0:printFormatRequest>
  </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

This is from the wsdl:

```xml
<xsd:complexType name="printFormat">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="objects">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="fObject" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="tns:objectTypePrint"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="jobID" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="numbers" type="xsd:int"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

I'm expecting a list of objects in the `<ns0:objects>` tag but it's empty.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by myself.

For other struggling with this problem:
zeep can show the loaded wsdl info with `client.wsdl.dump()`

The result contains this:

```
ns0:printFormat(objects: {fObject: ns0:objectTypePrint[]}, jobID: xsd:string, numbers: xsd:int)
```

So the working code for this method looks like:

```py
from lxml import etree
from requests import Session
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth  # or HTTPDigestAuth, or OAuth1, etc.
from zeep import Client
from zeep.transports import Transport

session = Session()
session.auth = HTTPDigestAuth('user', 'pass')
client = Client('http:service.local/services.wsdl',
    transport=Transport(session=session))

factory = client.type_factory('ns0')

o1 = factory.objectTypePrint('name1', 'val1') 
o2 = factory.objectTypePrint('name2', 'val2') 
o3 = factory.objectTypePrint('name3', 'val3') 
o = { 'fObject': [ o1, o2, o3 ] }

node =  client.create_message(client.service, 'printFormat', numbers=1, jobID='test', objects=o)

print(etree.tostring(node, pretty_print=True))
```

Comment: This is incredibly helpful! The output of client.wsdl.dump() makes everything super-clear!